# Find the number of ways to select $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ fruits from a pile (using generating functions)

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Find the number of ways to select $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ fruits from a pile of $3$ apples, $5$ oranges and $2$ bananas. (Use generating functions.)

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We encode zero up to

- *three apples* as: $\ \quad1+x+x^2+x^3=\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}$
- *five oranges* as: $\ \quad1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5=\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}$
- *two bananas* as: $\quad 1+x+x^2=\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}$

> Denoting with $[x^k]$ the coefficient of $x^k$ of a series, we are looking for
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^k]\frac{(1-x^4)(1-x^6)(1-x^3)}{(1-x)^3}}\qquad \qquad 1\leq k\leq 10
> \end{align*}
>
> We  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^k]&\frac{(1-x^4)(1-x^6)(1-x^3)}{(1-x)^3}\\
> &=[x^k](1-x^4)(1-x^6)(1-x^3)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-3}{j}(-x)^j\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^k](1-x^3-x^4-x^6+x^7+x^9+x^{10})\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{j+2}{2}x^j\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (2) we expand the factors up to powers of $x^{10}$ since higher powers do not contribute to $[x^k]$ for $1\leq k\leq 10$. We also apply the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.

> Example: We calculate from (2) the coefficient of  $x^k$  for $k=7$.
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^7]}&\color{blue}{(1-x^3-x^4-x^6+x^7+x^9+x^{10})\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{j+2}{2}x^j}\\
> &=\left([x^7]-[x^4]-[x^3]-[x^1]+[x^0]\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{j+2}{2}x^j\\
> &=\binom{9}{2}-\binom{6}{2}-\binom{5}{2}-\binom{3}{2}+\binom{2}{2}\\
> &=36-15-10-3+1\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=9}
> \end{align*}

The  $9$  solutions  of seven fruits are
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{apples}&\text{oranges}&\text{bananas}\\
\hline
3&4&0\\
3&3&1\\
3&2&2\\
2&5&1\\
2&4&1\\
2&3&2\\
1&5&1\\
1&4&2\\
0&5&2\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks, but I don't fully understand as I can't see what does $x$ stand for?

Comment: @JamesSmith: We  can select $0,1,2$ or $3$  apples.  This can  be written as sequence $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)=(0,1,2,3)$  and in  terms  of generating  functions we   write  the numbers as exponents 
  $x^{a_0}+x^{a_1}+x^{a_2}+x^{a_3}=x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3=1+x+x^2+x^3$  and in the same way for the  other  fruits.

Comment: The thing I still can't get is the fact that generating function is defined by the formula $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$. So shouldn't it be then $0 + x + 2x^2+3x^3$?

Comment: @JamesSmith: It is the *exponent*, which indicates the number of apples, while the coefficient $a_n$ in your example indicates the number of possibilities to obtain the specific number of apples. When picking from the pile of apples we have *one* possibility, to choose zero apples, so $1x^0=1$; we have *one* possibility to choose one apple (since they are indistinguishible), so $1x^1=x$. Continuing this way we have $1+x+x^2+x^3$, whereby $+$ means *(exclusive) or*.

Comment: @JamesSmith: An example with dice might be easier to conceive. We make a toss with three dice. The number of possibilities to obtain $4$ is the coefficient of $x^4$ in $(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^3$. You see?

Comment: Okey, I got it. Thank you

Comment: @JamesSmith: Great, you're welcome.

Comment: Have you maybe noted the final result?

Comment: @JamesSmith: I've added  some  details.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing, you consider choosing different fruits of same variety as identical choice, otherwise question will become straightforward.

So, suppose you have to pick $n$ fruits, where $n =1,2,3,...10$

You can seek no. of solution of equation $x_1 +x_2 +x_3 = n$,  for different values of $n$, where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ represent no. of apples, oranges and bananas.

By, generating function, you know it is $\binom {2+n}n$

For different values of $n$, it becomes $\sum_{n=1}^{10}\binom {2+n}n= \sum_{n=1}^{10}\binom {2+n}2 = \sum_{n=3}^{12}\binom {n}2 = \frac12 [ \sum_{n=3}^{12} n^2- \sum_{n=3}^{12}n] =285 $